# Trying to understand Lua simple codes

Tags: lua, lua-table, lua-patterns

I'm having some trouble with Lua. The thing is: there are some Lua codes I know what they do but I didn't understood them, so if the professors ask me to explain them, I wouldn't be able to do it.
Can you help me with this?

1. I know this code separates the integer part from the decimal part of a number, but I didn't understand the `"(%d*)(%.?.*)$"` part.

   ```
   int, dec = string.match(tostring(value), "(%d*)(%.?.*)$")
   ```
2. This code insert on a table all the data from a text file, which is written following this model `entry {name = "John", age = 20, sex = "Male")`. What I didn't understand is how do I know what parameters the function load needs? And the last parameter `entry = entry`, I don't know if I got exactly its meaning: I think it gets the `text_from_file` as a piece of Lua code and everything that is after entry is sent to the `function entry`, which inserts it on a table, is it right?

   ```
   function entry(entrydata)
       table.insert(data, entrydata)           
   end

   thunk = load(text_from_file, nil, nil, {entry = entry})
   thunk()
   ```

That's it. Please, if it's possible, help me understand these 2 pieces of Lua code, I need to present the whole program working and if a professor ask me about the code, I want to be sure about everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, you need to learn a little about [lua patterns](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial) and [`string.match`](http://lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.match).

The pattern `(%d*)(%.?.*)$` is comprised of two smaller ones. `%d*` and `%.?.*`. The `$` at the end merely indicates that the matching is to be done till the end of string `tostring(value)`. The `%d*` will match **0 or more** *numerical values* and store the result (if found, otherwise nil) t the variable `int`.

`%.?` matches a literal `.` character. The `?` means that the `.` may or may not be present. The `.*` matches everything and stores them into `dec` variable.

---

Similarly, for the second code segment, please go through the [`load()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-load) reference. You have the following text in your file:

```
entry {name = "John", age = 20, sex = "Male")
```

It is equivalent to executing a function named `entry` with **the parameter** (notice that I used parameter and not parameters) a table, as follows:

```
entry( {name = "John", age = 20, sex = "Male") )
```

The last parameter to `load` defines the environment for the loaded string. By passing `{entry = entry}`, you're defining an environment in which you have a function named `entry`. To understand it better, look at the changes in the following segment:

```
function myOwnFunctionName(entrydata)
    table.insert(data, entrydata)
end

thunk = load(text_from_file, nil, nil, {entry = myOwnFunctionName})
```

Now, the custom environment passed to `load` will have a variable named `entry` which is actually the function `myOwnFunctionName`.